# Running a function within a task

Tags: build.gradle

In build.gradle task, I want to check if a file exist, and if not - to download it by running another task.
However I can't figure how to call a function only if neseccary.

I used a gradle plugin allowing me to Download from web.
relevant code:

```
task DownloadWhitesourceAgent(type: Download) {
    from 'https://github.com/whitesource/unified-agent-distribution/releases/latest/download/wss-unified-agent.jar'
    to './wss-unified-agent.jar'
}

task updateWhitesourceBackend(type: Exec) {

    if(!file("wss-unified-agent.jar").exists()) {
        commandLine('echo', 'agent not found, downloding')
        DownloadWhitesourceAgent() //This calling is just not working
    }
    
}
```

I was thinking of using def instread of task, then call the function - but then it doesn't know how to use the gradle plugin.

Thanks for any guidance..